# Mathematical Quine

Tags: recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions

I have recently discovered that I can create letters and any shape I want by hiding parts of curves by making them complex. To generalise if I want $x>a$ then I multiply my function by $\sqrt{\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}\,}$ and replacing $x-a$ with $b-x$ I can make $x<b$.

The challenge I put forward is this:

***Create an equation or set of equations, which graph the equations themselves***

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: The empty set. :)

Comment: You could say the same for a computer program quine. An empty program will print itself out ie nothing. Clever thinking though

Comment: You'd pretty much have to give a complete language for curves and fonts before you could answer this question. I suppose there might be a general proof that there is always a quine, no matter what the font definitions and descriptive language...

Comment: @Jordan: My answer was an homage to that one. (that was actually the submission to the obfuscated C contest that put an end to that aspect of the competition)

Comment: You might be interested in [Tupper's self-referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula)

Comment: @JordanBrown judging by the looks of the screengrab, you're using the application that comes with os x? have you looked at the examples drop down menu? i think using parametric equations might be a bit simpler (some people might call this cheating)

Answer (score 2):

As Ross Millikan says in the comments, [Tupper's self-referential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) is a famous example.

Comment: +1, but Tupper's "self-referential" formula (which he never named so, in [the excellent paper where he used it as example](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf)) just takes a bitstring (the region) and forms a bitmap out of it. This is like a program that echoes its input: sure, when given its own code as input it does print it out, but that doesn't make it a quine. However, Jakub Trávník has written a true mathematical "quine", whose graph contains all the information necessary to recreate it: [here](http://jtra.cz/stuff/essays/math-self-reference/index.html).